# POST values through php header function

Tags: php

How to send values through post method in php header() function?

Suppose:

```
header("Location:index.php?abc=".$abc);
```

Instead of this get method or query string I want to pass value through post method, don't use session.

Comment: what is the question about; you didn't say what is working or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with headers only. For that you should use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (check [Basic curl example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)).

Comment: How? Please guide me.

Comment: See http://us1.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php . Init curl, set required URL, set CURLOPT_POST to true and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  to your post data and call curl_exec.